# UITextView doesn't display all of the text on small screens when using exclusions

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview

I have a UITextView:

```
var textView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.textColor = .orange
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.isEditable = false
    return textView
}()
```

I have it constrained to another view, which is in turn part of a UIStackView

```
    mainStack.axis = .vertical
    mainStack.addArrangedSubview(titleView)
    mainStack.addArrangedSubview(bodyView)
    
    titleView.addSubview(textView)
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let padding: CGFloat = 5
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  titleView.topAnchor, constant: padding),
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding)
    ])
```

In addition I have a button constrained partially in the same area

```
let mainActionButton = UIButton()
titleView.addSubview(mainActionButton)
        
mainActionButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mainActionButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.trailingAnchor),
            mainActionButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  titleView.topAnchor),
            mainActionButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainActionButton.widthAnchor)
        ])
```

At runtime, after viewDidLoad is called, I use the following to make sure the text flows around the button

```
    textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(rect: mainActionButton.frame)]
    self.layoutSubviews()
```

Generally, this works nicely, as you can see from the screenshot:

[image: working]

**However**, when I changed the padding to anything less than 4 in the constraints for the uitextview, on **small screens only**, it does not display the last line, as you can see below:

[image: not working]

Again, this doesn't happen if:

- There is no exclusion path (button)
- It is on a large screen
- The padding is more than 3 px

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Does the problem happen if `titleView` is not added to a stack view? Maybe the issues is because of `bodyView` and the stack view's constraints on the smaller screen.

Comment: @HangarRash nice! I should've thought of that. That solved the issue.

Comment: I spoke too soon, still having issues with long names, even on large devices.

Comment: @MosesHarding - you need to provide more details... I put together a quick test -- *trying to guess at your layout / constraints* -- and I'm not seeing the problem you're showing. Shouldn't take you more than a couple minutes to put together enough code for a [mre].

Comment: @DonMag thanks for pointing that example out. In the process of putting together the test I found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your *"minimum reproducible example"* ...

I've found in the past that when setting `.exclusionPaths` in a `UITextView`, the **layout** needs to be "prompted" to update. It also seems much more reliable to set the `.text` *after* setting the exclusion paths.

Also - while not related to what's going on here - I find it very helpful during development to give UI elements contrasting background colors to make it easy to see the framing at run-time.

So, here is your example, almost as-is, with these changes:

- constrained `PrimaryView` to the safe-area
- gave `bodyView` a height, and added a label as a subview to identify it
- gave all the views background colors

---

**your "helper" function** - unmodified

```
// Helper function
extension UIView {
    enum ConstraintType: CaseIterable { case leading, trailing, top, bottom }
    func constrain(_ child: UIView, padding: CGFloat = 0, except: [ConstraintType] = []) {
        
        self.addSubview(child)
        child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        for type in ConstraintType.allCases where !except.contains(type) {
            switch type {
            case .leading:
                child.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
            case .trailing:
                child.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
            case .top:
                child.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
            case .bottom:
                child.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**view controller class** - modified to respect safe-area

```
class ExclusionTestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let primaryView = MyPrimaryView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //self.view.constrain(primaryView)
        
        primaryView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(primaryView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            primaryView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            primaryView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            primaryView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            primaryView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        primaryView.layoutTitle()
    }
}
```

---

**`PrimaryView` class** - original, except added colors and bodyView properties

```
class MyPrimaryView: UIView {
    
    var mainScroll = UIScrollView()
    
    var mainStack: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        return stackView
    } ()
    
    var titleTextView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isEditable = false
        return textView
    }()
    var mainActionButtonArea = UIView()
    var mainActionButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "square.and.pencil.circle.fill", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 36)), for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    var bodyView = UIStackView()
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        setUpMainStack()

        // set background colors to make it easy to see framing
        self.backgroundColor = .cyan
        mainScroll.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        mainStack.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        titleTextView.backgroundColor = .green
        mainActionButtonArea.backgroundColor = .red.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
        mainActionButton.backgroundColor = .white
        bodyView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
        // let's give the bodyView a height constraint of 180
        bodyView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180.0).isActive = true
        // and add a label to identify it
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 24.0)
        v.text = "Body View"
        bodyView.constrain(v, padding: 12.0, except: [.trailing, .bottom])
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setUpMainStack() {
        
        // Constrain scrollview to view
        self.constrain(mainScroll, padding: 30)
        
        // Constrain UIStackView to scroll view
        mainScroll.constrain(mainStack)
        mainScroll.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStack.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // Add child views
        mainStack.addArrangedSubview(titleTextView)
        mainStack.addArrangedSubview(bodyView)
        
        titleTextView.text = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19"
        
        // Add action button area + action button
        mainScroll.constrain(mainActionButtonArea, except: [.leading, .bottom])
        mainActionButtonArea.constrain(mainActionButton, padding: 10)
        mainActionButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainActionButton.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        
    }
            
    func layoutTitle() {
        // This adds the exception path; needs to be called after subviews are already laid out
        let buttonPath = UIBezierPath(rect: mainActionButtonArea.frame)
        titleTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [buttonPath]
    }
    
}
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

As you pointed out, the "17 18 19" line is missing.

So, let's force the text view to update its layout when we set the exclusion path. The **only** change will be a few lines added here:

```
func layoutTitle() {
    // This adds the exception path; needs to be called after subviews are already laid out
    let buttonPath = UIBezierPath(rect: mainActionButtonArea.frame)
    titleTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [buttonPath]
    
    // "re-set" the text view's text and force a layout pass
    let str: String = titleTextView.text ?? ""
    titleTextView.text = ""
    titleTextView.text = str
    titleTextView.setNeedsLayout()
    titleTextView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Now when we run it, we get:

[image]

and there's no need to create a temporary label with sizing calculations that may, or may not, be reliable and flexible.

---

As a side note, to get this to "play well" with dynamic size changes - such as device rotation - it's still got a bit of work to do.

Comment: Interesting - so I guess even though the actual text in the text view flowed around the exclusion path, the text view itself didn't update to accommodate the new height required. Well, certainly a much better solution than having to add an arbitrary number of extra pixels to make it work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not 100% sure *why* this was happening, I think it's because I had placed the UITextView in a stackview that was also in a scrollview, and therefore it was never getting any hard definition of a content size.

What I did was create a method that is called after the view is loaded, which calculates the intrinsic content size of a label that would be in the same location using 'systemLayoutSizeFitting' (and of course subtracting any extra padding / width'). I took that height value and set a hard constraint. For some reason, I had to add 30 to make it work properly - there must be some other aspect of the textfield that adds 30 px of padding.

```
func layoutTitle() {
    
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = Fonts.titleFont
    label.numberOfLines = -1
    label.text = titleTextView.text
    
    let size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width - (padding * 2) - mainActionButton.frame.width, height: 0)
    let newSize = label.systemLayoutSizeFitting(size, withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)
    
    var height = newSize.height + 30

    titleTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: height).isActive = true
}
```

**NOTE** I'm adding a minimum reproducible example below; you should be able to pop this into the view controller file of a single view app. The tricky part is that different lengths of string work on different phones, but if you run the iPhone 14 Pro Max simulator, you'll see that only up to the number 16 appears, hiding 17, 18, and 19. If you then add '20' to the titleTextView's text, it appears again.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let primaryView = PrimaryView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.constrain(primaryView)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        primaryView.layoutTitle()
    }
}

class PrimaryView: UIView {
    
    var viewController: UIViewController!
    
    var mainScroll = UIScrollView()

    var mainStack: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        return stackView
    } ()
    
    var titleTextView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isEditable = false
        return textView
    }()
    var mainActionButtonArea = UIView()
    var mainActionButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "square.and.pencil.circle.fill", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 36)), for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    var bodyView = UIStackView()
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        setUpMainStack()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setUpMainStack() {
        
        // Constrain scrollview to view
        self.constrain(mainScroll, padding: 30)
        
        // Constrain UIStackView to scroll view
        mainScroll.constrain(mainStack)
        mainScroll.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStack.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // Add child views
        mainStack.addArrangedSubview(titleTextView)
        mainStack.addArrangedSubview(bodyView)
         
        titleTextView.text = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19"
        
        // Add action button area + action button
        mainScroll.constrain(mainActionButtonArea, except: [.leading, .bottom])
        mainActionButtonArea.constrain(mainActionButton, padding: 10)
        mainActionButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainActionButton.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    

    func layoutTitle() {
        // This adds the exception path; needs to be called after subviews are already laid out
        let buttonPath = UIBezierPath(rect: mainActionButtonArea.frame)
        titleTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [buttonPath]
    }
}

// Helper function
extension UIView {
    enum ConstraintType: CaseIterable { case leading, trailing, top, bottom }
    func constrain(_ child: UIView, padding: CGFloat = 0, except: [ConstraintType] = []) {

        self.addSubview(child)
        child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        for type in ConstraintType.allCases where !except.contains(type) {
                switch type {
                case .leading:
                    child.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
                case .trailing:
                    child.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
                case .top:
                    child.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
                case .bottom:
                    child.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like something else is going on -- you shouldn't have to do that. And it's risky to use a *"**seems** to work by adding this..."* fix, as it may or may not continue to work. If you put up a [mre] we can take a better look at it.

Comment: @DonMag Sure - I added. I appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: Added an answer, based on your MRE